# How big can call stack be before this code causes trouble?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack-overflow

I optimized linked list destructor like this:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    /* snip */
    T* pData;
    LinkedList* pNext;
};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    delete pData;
    delete pNext;
}
```

Now I'm a bit worried that it may cause trouble on large lists. Can this code cause stack overflow? If so, on how big lists?

Comment: I don't see where the stack overflow could occur?

Comment: @TonyTheLion: The line `delete pNext;` seems to be calling destructor calling destructor calling destructor and so on.

Comment: Wow: seriously dangerous code: a constructor that doesn't set pointers and a destructor that assumes they are dynamically allocated on the heap. Nothing at all to do with stack overflows though...

Comment: @TonyTheLion pNext is LinkedList* so call stack only grows for each element in list.

Comment: @John3136 There is a construtor, i just removed irrelevant code...

Comment: @John3136: I don't assume it is the complete code. Why did you assume so? It doesn't have many other details, possibly that includes the constructor also.

Comment: @MislavBlažević - you've removed too much ;-) There isn;t enough left to show why you think there is a stack problem.

Comment: @billz Where are possible memory leaks?

Comment: @John3136 Nawaz's observation is correct. There *may* be problem with this code.

Comment: @Nawaz - there is so little there, and the code doesn't seem to relate to the question, so I assumed (and I might be 100% wrong) that OP doesn't really understand dynamic memory, constructors, destructors, stack etc.

Comment: @John3136 I don't think you understand this code. Try to look at line delete pNext again.

Comment: @MislavBlažević Yep, you are right. I missed the fact it is a recursive destructor (you might want to comment that!) so there is stack involved, so it's a fair question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the stack is determined by a number of factors, such as the OS/compiler/configuration settings on the system.

I would definitely not use a recursive method to delete the elements in the list, as you may well overflow the stack - you can try this by creating a list with X elements, and if that works, double X, until you reach a stack overflow - I pretty much guarantee that it happens within a few thousand elements (maybe 10-100k, but certainly not much more than that).

Recursive functions for deleting binary trees and such are much more acceptable, because (assuming reasonable balance) the number of recursive levels are `log2(n)`, rather than `n`, so you can have a huge number of elements before the stack overflows.

I took your class and expanded it to make it "work" (this is probably nothing like how you use it, but it does the job to explain the problem):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList() : pNext(0), pData(0) {};
    LinkedList(T e) : pNext(0) { pData = new T(e); }
    LinkedList(LinkedList* l, T e) : LinkedList(e) { pNext = l;}

    LinkedList *AppendFirst(LinkedList *l) { l->pNext = this ; return l; }

    LinkedList *Next() { return pNext; }

    T Data() { return *pData; }

    ~LinkedList();
private:
    T* pData;
    LinkedList* pNext;
};

#if 0
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    delete pData;
    delete pNext;
};
#else
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    LinkedList<T>* p;
    LinkedList<T>* q;
    p = pNext;
    while(p)
    {
        q = p->pNext;   // Save next link. 
        p->pNext = NULL;   // Break the link. 
        delete p->pData;
        p->pData = NULL;
        delete p;
        p = q;
    }

    delete pData;
};
#endif


typedef LinkedList<int> IntList;

int main()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
    {
        cout << "Trying " << (1 << x) << " elements" << endl;
        IntList *head = new IntList(-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < (1 << x); i++)
        {
            head = head->AppendFirst(new IntList(i));
        }
        cout << "Now destroying " << (1 << x) << " elements" << endl;
        delete head;
    }
}
```

If I change the `#if 0` to `#if 1` (or something else with that effect), it works for 128K elements and crashes at 256K. If I use the iterative method in the `#else`, I had to stop it when it got to 268435456 (256M entries) because my machine didn't have enough memory, and started swapping badly (I only have 16GB of RAM, and it's not JUST doing that).